# htaccess : how to specify default missing image in folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I do display images from 
mysite.com/upload/cropped/{username}.jpg

Is there a way to create an .htaccess so missing images inside

mysite.com/upload/cropped/{username}.jpg are replaced by

mysite.com/upload/cropped/defaultAvatar.jpg ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done using this rewrite rule in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(upload/cropped)/[^.]+\.jpg$ /$1/defaultAvatar.jpg [NC,L]
```

Assuming that there is no other `.htaccess` in your system in sub directories.